# for loop doesn't after looping throw the script

Tags: php

i have php script to do for loop, it supposed to loop over the code once and then exit,but theses not happening, it keep looping till i exited manually.

my code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);

for( $x=0; $x< 50; )

{

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

$st = $_SESSION['timeout'] + 1;

session_unset();

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

$st = $_SESSION['timeout'] + 1;

print_r("$st\n");

}

if(time() < $st)
{

file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest1234.txt', 'test');

}

?>
```

Comment: @Dagon - Not to mention that even if `$x++` was included, there's still looking at *fifty iterations* of the loop, not one.

Comment: what about the if statement is going to execute ? after session time out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an infite loop. $x always stays at 0.

```
for( $x=0; $x< 50; )
```

You need to do:

```
for( $x=0; $x< 50; $x++)
```

[php man "for"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: what about the if statement is going to execute ? after session time out ?

Comment: when the for loop is over, the program goes on to the next line of code. the if block will execute if the conditions are true. Unlike before, when it would run the for loop indefinitely and it would never move on to the if block. Did you mean for the if block to be inside the for loop?

Comment: if you see my code there's session time out. i would like the if statement to be run when the session over.

Comment: Why are you using a for loop? you want it to loop over the code once -- makes no sense if you want it to run through the code only once. Looping implies going back over. Anyway, have the if statement be `if(isset($st)){` , then if the session timeout is set the if block will run

Comment: look what im trying to accomplish, i have javascript pulling my script every interval second. if javascript stop pulling my script. block in if statement  should run. can you help me with this ?

Comment: you're not doing it every second, you're doing it as often as it reiterates the 'for' loop. often times 1/1000th of a second. Try a while loop. Do something different. I can't see what you're trying to accomplish. For example, why are you running `$_SESSION['timeout'] = time(); $st = $_SESSION['timeout'] + 1;` twice? what does `if(time() < $st)` accomplish, if $st is just `time() + 1` ?

Comment: can you please write for me the script please for what i need. thank you