# Php loop not stopping

Tags: php

I have a php script and I'm facing problems in my script.

Look what I have accomplished in my script, the problem in my script is when  `session_destroy();` and `unset($_SESSION['timeout']);` happen, it's supposed to kill `timeout` then `while loop if(time() >  $st)` will stop. But these is not happening, it keeps looping and executes what's inside the while loop. I'm wondering why. Can you look in my code and see?

My code:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
?>


<?php
    for( $x=0; $x< 50; $x++ ) {
        $st = $_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + 10;
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['timeout']);
    }

    $loop = true;

    while($loop) {
        if(time() >  $st) {
            file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest1234.txt', 'test');
            $loop=false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if(time() <  $st) use this

Comment: @Abhishek no still execute what inside the loop.

Comment: Can you use `var_dump` to see what is the value of `$st` right before the while loop? `time()` is never returning a value greater than what `$st` contains.

Comment: check value of time() and $st to debug it

Comment: Put a `sleep(1)` in the loop and debug the values.

Comment: i already used print_r() it returning some value numbers.

Comment: please don't create a new account to ask the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499679/for-loop-doesnt-after-looping-throw-the-script

Comment: i dont think there's a problem, it stops, [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DdnMgm)

Answer (score 0):

It **doesn't** run forever, it's just the **overload** of delay that the frequent calls to `time()` causes, which makes it appear as if it took forever to run, specially on a slow server (or computer, which I guess its your case). For instance, on a single second (`$st = time() + 1`) the system can make 1,000,000's of calls to the `time()` function, multiply that times 10 (`$st = time() + 1`) and you have an almost locked up server. In this case I suggest you use a *less aggresive* method to measure your timeout, like using the `sleep()` function (this is a very simplificated version of your code):

```
$st = time() + 5;

while(true) {
    $t = time();      
    if( $t > $st ) {
        echo 'loop finshed';
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

So it'll sleep 1 second every loop until it reaches or exceeds the timeout without overloading the CPU with `time()` calls. The `sleep()` function works with seconds, so the minimum is 1 second, but if only 1 is not enough for you, you can use the `usleep()` function, that sleeps the execution in terms of *microseconds*. So if you want to sleep the thread for a 1/20th of a second, you can change `sleep()` for:

```
usleep(50000);
```

More information about [sleep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) and [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) on the PHP's manual pages.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this not solving  my problem, if you see my code you will notice that im using `session_destroy();` and `unset($_SESSION['timeout']);`it supposed to kill the timeout and stop while loop from happening.but this not working. can you fix it ?

Comment: Unsetting the `$_SESSION['timeout']` var won't stop your loop, you would have to manually set your `$st` to a value smaller than it initially was so it prevents the loop to continue. Also, I think you can't do what you want with the approach you're currently implementing. You would most certainly have to use [threads](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php) to do what you want, but that requires another question.